# running scripts with bundle exec is slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

When running with bundle exec

```
$ time bundle exec rails generate model student name:string age:number
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20121215170617_create_students.rb
      create    app/models/student.rb

real    0m13.397s
user    0m11.676s
sys     0m0.597s
```

Running directly

```
$ time rails generate model student name:string age:number
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20121215171018_create_students.rb
      create    app/models/student.rb

real    0m6.408s
user    0m5.783s
sys     0m0.510s

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]
```

so, normal the command takes 6seconds but with `bundle exec`, its slow & takes twice the the time.

so, is just me or `bundle exec` is just slow?

Comment: Considering `bundle exec` has to setup proper context for your command to run inside of *(ensuring all of the gems of the proper version **and only** them are loaded)*, is this really a surprise? More steps/setup = more work by your computer = more time required to finish.

Comment: Yes, 13seconds to create a file is bit too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bundle exec` with `rails` command is redundant.

> So don't run bundle exec before rails command, this command is already
>   aware of Bundler and sets up everything according to what you have on
>   your Gemfile. If you prepend bundle exec before rails command all you
>   will be adding is overhead of opening another process from Bundler and
>   executing useless code since rails already does the right thing.

Gotten from [here](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/12/27/bundle-exec-rails-executes-bundler-setup-3-times/).

Comment: @GaurishSharma If you don't know, Santiago Pastorino (the author of these words) is a Rails core team member. So it not just "makes sense", it's more like: "do it this way, I know what I'm talking about" :)