# `bundle exec` very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

- Ruby version:

  ```
  ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
  ```
- Bundle version:

  ```
  Bundler version 1.7.3
  ```
- Rails version

  ```
  Rails 4.1.5
  ```
- System is Gentoo in Vagrant

When I execute command `bundle exec annotate` :

```
Nothing annotated.
bundle exec annotate  4.33s user 54.82s system 46% cpu 2:08.45 total
```

Rake command is very slowly too，for example `bundle exec rake db:migrate`:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate  4.31s user 55.93s system 53% cpu 1:51.99 total
```

I found the question [running scripts with bundle exec is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894966/running-scripts-with-bundle-exec-is-slow), but when I execute the command `time bin/rake db:migrate`, it's very slow too:

```
bin/rake db:migrate  3.58s user 49.47s system 45% cpu 1:55.34 total
```

So can anyone tell me what's wrong happened?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-clone the repo and execute command `bundle install`, the problem has been resolved.

Comment: did not work for me